# Are there any alternatives to Floobits with GIT/CVS like editor logging

Tags: git, svn, intellij-idea, liveedit

I love Floobits, but for this project I need an alternative that keeps track of who and when makes changes to a document, specifically because we're doing this project as part of a degree and the teaching staff want a way of keeping track of who's contributing to the team work.

They've suggested GIT and CVS(Subversion) for obvious reasons (widely used, industry standard, etc. etc.) but honestly I hate these systems because they don't work when you need more than one person to be able to edit the code at the same time. Hence my discovery and use of Floobits. I know you can run Floobits and GIT in parallel (with a supported IDE, we will be using a Jetbrains built IDE, we will likely be using Java so it will probably be IntelliJ) but when we make a commit to the GIT all changes would be credited to whoever did the push. So.... that's not an option.

Don't need opinions. Just a solution cause surely I'm not the first person to encounter this problem!?

I will accept hacks that involve custom server setups so long as the 'end user' setup isn't overly complicated.

Comment: just had a look at cloud9. It looks great but.... it doesn't allow for different users to use their own Git accounts. Only the workspace creator which means it's not much better than the Floobits solution. :/

Comment: From your second paragraph, I don't think you really understand how git & Subversion actually work and are meant to be used.

Comment: Educate me. My impression is that it's designed to keep projects with distributed teams in sync and provide centralize code access, with a focus on tools for tracking who has made edits when the edits were made and facilities for easily rolling back to previous versions. From my perspective at this stage it fails to adequately satisfy the first point. Does fine on the others but personally if the sync abilities aren't real time and automated they're worthless.

Comment: Git & Subversion are both designed to manage people working on the same files at the same time, and then merge the changes together (which *may* require manual intervention if two people change the same parts of the same files). And with both, "all changes  would be credited to whoever did the push" is not true - when you commit, you give your own credentials, and the user who committed the changes is recorded with the change.

Comment: In the situation I'm describing with Floobits the statement "all changes would be credited to whoever did the push" would be true unless you know something I don't. Because when you push to the GIT you have everyone's code changes loaded on your version of the files and visa versa.

Comment: But the commit *history* should still show who committed what (by default, when you `git push` you're sending a history of *all* local commits which is then appended to the master and not just the current state. Unless Floobits is doing something different). If that's lost, then you have no accountability in your system and that's a bad way to run things.

Comment: Yeah.... floobits doesn't have any versioning hence the hunt for an alternative. It just live streams the position of other editors cursor locations and the edits they're making to the code. So when one user push's they're pushing all changes made locally and otherwise and Git's not going to have a clue whether all those changes came from that user or not.

Comment: So I did figure out how to solve this issue but.... floobits isn't open source. So... yeah. I can't fix it.

In short the idea is for Floobits to right to the git change log file each time the editor moves to a new line recording before and after changes just like a git push event would. Obviously it would need to know the git username of each editor at the IDE level but... that could be arranged or possibly figured out by additional hooks into the IDE config files in the project directories. The overall effect would be to virtualize pushes into a secondary git server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so at this point in time there is no protocol or service that has the features required to fit the above description (I was going to just edit my question but this is valid as a solution answer if only until someone like myself actually implements the prototype.)

At this stage a good solution would be a cloud based editor running on an asynchronous server system like Node.js (cloud9 operates in a similar method to what is required) where it would be possible to maintain synchronicity at an editor level independently of each persons changes to their copy of the files. The system would be a pain debug but once operating

Each new user could: 
1. Login with a GIT/CVS/Mercurial account
2. The environment would clone a copy of the latest code.
3. They could then edit in real time and see others changes as they were being made.
4. Then make commits and pulls based solely off of the code contained in their copy of the files whilst still being able to see others non-committed changes (such changes would need to be marked as such, locked to prevent parallel editing unless invited by the original author [limited collaborative programming] and labeled with the original authors userId.

Components of the system as proposed:

1. Node.js server(easy)
2. HTML based real time synchronized editor (easy)
3. GIT integration per user with associated separation of synchronized file copies whilst keeping changes made in real time. (not so easy)
4. Merge 2 and 3 into the one system (I make a change: my copy of the files are update and the common editing environment displays a locked section of code with the respective users original code in parallel with the changes I've made (GIT difference resolution GUI style); others make changes: my code is unaffected but I can see the changes they've made however I can't make changes to my copy of that code block)

In the future

5. Allow for parallel changes to the same block of code and allow for all users to see all the different changes for each section of code that haven't been committed to the central repository. All users have access to virtually unlimited forks of the main code base but the forks only contain code for a specific section of the document and not the whole project.

Simplest break down I can achieve if you're still not getting it. (I'm rereading this and my head is spinning) We use 2 parallel versioning systems.

1. The top level (the editor) takes changes as they're made and makes them available to all users whilst showing who's made the relevant changes.
2. The second level (the traditional method) maintains separations of each users code and only commits the changes once the user request's changes to be merged to the central repository.

In theory this is how the existing system works but... there's no simple way of viewing other peoples forks of the code base while they're still editing. Unless you're using web based systems like Github or Stash. And even then you can't see the code until they've committed to their fork and I've seen time and time again files that are so out of date to the central repo that GIT can't resolve changes made on a fork with the other changes that have already been merged because the line numbers and code have changed so drastically.

Anyway, that's my take on a solution to the problem. I know a lot of people are happy with the current non synchronous systems that are already in use but... From my experience with teamwork at UNI thus far, there is a massive need for some form of synchronous editing environment whilst still offering the accountability provided by the existing GIT/CVS/Mercurial systems.